# Swift issue when using Parse's signup in background with block

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I've issue with Swift when using Parse's signup in background with block

```
  func Signup()
        {
            var user = PFUser()
            user.username = self.username.text
            user.password = self.password.text
            user.email = "email@example.com"


            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error != nil)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
                }
            }
        }
```

then I got these two errors

http://s15.postimg.org/geexdxwob/image.png

Comment: Post your code and your error in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  func Signup()
        {
            var user = PFUser()
            user.username = self.username.text
            user.password = self.password.text
            user.email = "email@example.com"


            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool , error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error != nil)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `userInfo` like that. You should use the `error.code` instead.

[Check what the error-codes represent.](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm)

Also the other error should disappear, because I've tested it, and it works. So just remove the line

```
let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
```

`And work with error.code instead and with switch-cases where you handle the different error-codes and build a errorString by yourself.

```
 user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            var errorString:String!
            switch error.code{
            case 100:
                errorString = "Error 100 appeared. It means..."
            case 101:
                errorString = "Error 101 appeared. It means..."
            case 102:
                errorString = "Error 102 appeared. It means..."
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        else{

        }
    }
```

Comment: well , I still get the first error "function signuate ' (bool!,NSError!)..."

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx8ag1t5o0qoffe/104%20-%20Login%20%26%20Signup.zip?dl=0